# How to get all selected values from a multi-select when some values are disabled?

Tags: jquery

I think this is a bug, but what I have read in this [bug ticket](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13097) is that the alleged smart people charged with safeguarding jquery say this is not considered a bug (even though disabled items were returned in version prior to 1.8.3). [See comment 8](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13097#comment:8).

I was checking for value like so

```
$(ele).val();
```

however when only disabled items are in a selected state the result is []

i thought that perhaps I could get them like the following, but the result is ""

```
$(ele).find("option[selected]").val();
```

I also tried the following and it returned an array of the options, not an array of values.

```
$(ele).find("option[selected]").val([]);
```

Please don't make me explain why there are selected, disabled items in the list .... lets just leave it at very complex and uncompromising business rules.

Comment: So basically: a selected value will not return if it's disabled?

Comment: That bug report is about select-single, not select-multiple.

Comment: Correct.A selected value will not return if it's disabled.

Comment: not about multi's but same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `option:selected`, not `option[selected]`. The latter only matches options that have the `selected` attribute in their HTML; you have to use `:selected` to test their current state of selection.

Also, `.val()` only returns the value of the first element selected. If you want to get all the values of a multi-select, you need to map over them.

```
var selected_values = $(ele).find("option:selected").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: For example, when 2 items are in a selected status and NOT disabled $(ele).val() returns ["4", "8"]. When those same selected items are disabled, $(ele).val() returns []

Comment: @user3071434 But the question is about being able to retrieve disabled options as well.

Comment: retrieve disabled "selected" items ..... sorry if my question was unclear. I want to retrieve all selected items .... enable and disabled alike

Comment: Isn't that what my answer does?

Comment: You answers works perfectly ... I was replying to you 2nd line about ".val() only returns the value of the first element selected" ... which does is not how my browser appears to be behaving. I want the answer, but I also want to understand the behavior and learn.

Comment: If the selector matches `<select>` elements, it returns the value of the first `<select>`. That value will be an array if it's a multi-select. If the selector matches `<option>` elements, it returns the value of the first matching option, which is not an array.